# PyGame Grid Surface Not Updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a grid based game and I want it so that if I click on a certain cell on the screen it will become colored. For some reason, this is not working and I can't figure out why. I have used a 2D array system to index my graphical grid and if I manually preset a value in the array like this:

```py
grid = [ [1]*8 for n in range(8)]
grid[6][7] = -1
```

It works fine and the cell is colored.

However, using the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, I get the position of the mouse and correctly identify the location of the mouse and which cell the mouse clicked on. I log to the console and see that the array is being correctly updated and the correct coordinates of the mouse and cell clicked on are being shown.

Here is the full script:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((900,900))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
board = pygame.image.load('Assets/boardfull.png')
pygame.draw.rect(win, (243, 235, 215), (0, 0, 900, 900))
pygame.display.update()
board = pygame.transform.scale(board, (900,900))
GAME_RUN = True
WIDTH = 112.5
HEIGHT = 112.5
MARGIN = 2
pawn_x = -60
pawn_y = 600
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
grid = [ [1]*8 for n in range(8)]
grid[6][7] = -1
gridcolumn = 0
gridrow = 0

while GAME_RUN == True:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    #GAME LOGIC
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GAME_RUN = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = int(pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN))
            row = int(pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN))
            # Set that location to one
            grid[row][column] = -1
            print(grid)
            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)
    #GRID
    for row in grid:
        for col in row:
            color = WHITE
            if col == -1:
                color = RED
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (color), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 112.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win,(BLACK), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 2))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (BLACK), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 2, 112.5))
            gridcolumn = gridcolumn + 1
        gridrow = gridrow + 1
        gridcolumn = 0

    #UPDATE SURFACE
    pygame.display.update()




pygame.quit()
quit()
```

There are no error messages. Simply nothing happens and the program keeps running. Possibly the display isn't being updated correctly? I honestly have no clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT (real solution):

Well, I guess I found the real reason. Essentially, everything's okay. The only problem is that your `gridRow` wasn't being reset. Just add the `gridRow = 0` after `gridColumn=0` (but not in the `for row in grid:` loop), and it fixes the problem. This should be your update code now:

```
while GAME_RUN == True:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    #GAME LOGIC
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GAME_RUN = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = int(pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN))
            row = int(pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN))
            # Set that location to one
            grid[row][column] = -1
            print(grid)
            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)
    #GRID
    for row in grid:
        for col in row:
            color = WHITE
            if col == -1:
                color = RED
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (color), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 112.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win,(BLACK), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 2))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (BLACK), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 2, 112.5))
            gridcolumn = gridcolumn + 1
        gridrow = gridrow + 1
        gridcolumn = 0
    gridrow = 0
    #UPDATE SURFACE
    pygame.display.update()
```

### Non-Working Solution (doesn't work nicely imo, bad):

*Okay, so I couldn't really find a proper reason why this is happening, but I was able to fix it. Essentially, you have to move `pygame.draw.rect(win, (color), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 112.5))` to here:*

```
            # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = int(pos[0] // (WIDTH + MARGIN))
            row = int(pos[1] // (HEIGHT + MARGIN))
            # Set that location to red (this is where you would put it, with the correct changes [column,row instead of gridcolumn,gridrow])
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (RED), (112.5 * column, 112.5 * row, 112.5, 112.5))
            print(grid)
            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)
```

*What I think the problem is that `GridRow` and `GridColumn` is returning something different than the `column` and `row`. My reasoning being that if we fix the GRID code a bit, it'll only set the color on the row. The column seems to always stay the 7th one.
The code that I replaced:*

```
    for row in grid:
        for col in row:
            color = WHITE
            if col == -1:
                # not setting properly
                color = RED
            if (color == RED):
                print(gridcolumn,gridrow)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (color), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 112.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win,(BLACK), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 112.5, 2))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (BLACK), (112.5 * gridcolumn, 112.5 * gridrow, 2, 112.5))
            gridcolumn = gridcolumn + 1
        gridrow = gridrow + 1
        gridcolumn = 0
    # never got reset, therefore gridrow would go over 7
    gridrow = 0
```

*Changing GRID code vs drawing immediately after click:
GRIDCODE:*
[image]

*Drawing immediately after click:*
[image]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! You fixed my problem has been fixed!